# Telling GORM not to persist a property

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way of telling GORM not to persist a property? I'm planning to define a confirm password property on my User class that I'll use for validation, but shouldn't be persisted.

Comment: Note that Command objects are often a better way of solving this problem. They can have properties that are submitted from the form, but aren't necessarily part of the domain object: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using transient key word GORM can be directed not to persist specific property.

Following code snippets shows the use of transient proerties

```
class Book {
  static transients = [ "digitalCopy" ]

  static constraints = {
    releaseDate(nullable: true)
  }    

  String author
  String title
  Date releaseDate
  File digitalCopy
}
```

digitalCopy property included in transient declaration notifies GORM not to persist digitalCopy

Answer (score 2):

OK - just managed to answer my own question with some more searching. Should have been more patient.
A static `transients` property "defines a list of property names that should not be persisted to the database. This is often useful if you have read-only getters that include logic."

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html