# Grails: derived fields in domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, derived

Suppose I have a domain class `branch` which has several members:

```
…
static hasMany = [ members:Member ];
…
```

Now suppose I want to have the number of members of that branch readily available, to have it displayed in the `list` and `view` actions, so perhaps storing that information into a variable in the domain class itself would be a good idea?

```
…
Integer memberCount = members.size();
static constraints = {
    memberCount(editable:false);
}
…
```

*(Is this the correct syntax?)* **Edit**: This is not the correct syntax. I cannot assess the size of the members list, as it doesn’t exist yet and grails will complain about size() not being applicable to null objects. What else could I try?

However, as `memberCount` is now a variable in the domain class, it is possible to assign a value to it upon creation of the `Branch` (which is contra-intuitive) and it will not be updated automatically once a new `Member` is added.

It is of course possible to reach the desired result in a different way. I could manipulate the `view.gsp` and `list.gsp` in the `/Branch` directory, add some additional `<td>`s there etc. But that does not seem very elegant to me.

Basically, I think what I am looking for is some way to tell grails that a certain variable is ***derived***, should not be setable by the user, but update whenever necessary. Is there such way?

Answer (score 2):

You can add any property you don't want persisted to the `transients` static list:

```
static transients = ['memberCount']
```

See [this page in the manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html)

Also, [this StackOverflow question answers the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846489/telling-gorm-not-to-persist-a-property)

---

Also, a better way to do derived properties may be to use the [Derived Properties feature of GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties)

Comment: If the `memberCount` property is in the `transients` lists, it won’t be stored in the database all right. But will it update once a new `Member` is added? It seems to me I will have to use the derived property feauture of GORM which you linked.